# Are you allowed to borrow money from another Jew with interest?

Tags: halacha, lending-interest-ribbis

So ... I understand you're not allowed to lend money to another Jew with interest, I won't get into the question of why.

Does this mean you're also not allowed to accept money from another Jew, where the contract dictates you need to pay an interest on this loan? E.g. a standard bank loan in Israel?

I assume that whether that other Jew is an atheist or not has no bearing on the matter, correct?

Comment: there are at least 2 separate questions here -- one being about the Israeli banking system and one about the responsibility of the borrower when entering into a loan contract. There are many opinions about the latter question reflected in articles online. Here is one to start with http://www.jlaw.com/Articles/ribis6.html . This article says that the borrower may not pay the interest of any sort, so it is on him as well as the lender http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5757/behar.html

Comment: @Dan, I think it's only multiple questions from the POV of someone who already knows more than this question's POV assumes. A complete answer would explain what you and DoubleAA have as well as heter iska.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mishna ([Bava Metzia 75b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=75b&format=pdf)) lists the different people who violate Biblical prohibitions when a loan is given with interest:

> ואלו עוברין בלא תעשה המלוה **והלוה** והערב והעדים וחכמים אומרים אף הסופר
>   These violate a negative commandment: the one who loans, **the one who borrows**, the guarantor, the witnesses, and the Sages say even the scribe who writes the document.

(The Gemara below explains that the scribe would be in violation of putting a stumbling block before the blind by allowing the others to perform the violation.)

Comment: This answer does not deal with your latter point about the status of non-beleiving/practicing Jews.

Comment: I guess the bible doesn't give any discounts to atheists, as was already explained to me here - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23519/can-a-jew-own-a-business-that-employs-or-pays-atheist-jews-on-shabbat Also, regarding banks, I will add that I heard that banks in Israel have "special arrangements" that make it so religious Jews won't violate any prohibitions while taking a loan (I don't know what those arrangements are though)

Comment: @ripper234 Indeed there are certain legal loopholes that are utilized in some cases, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heter_iska#Exemptions_and_evasions http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/1490 http://www.jlaw.com/Articles/heter1.html and an example document http://www.dinonline.org/files/2010/02/Heter-Iska.pdf.