# Employment questions I have

Tags: halacha, shabbat, employment

I have three questions.

1) Can a religious Orthodox Jewish employer, refuse to employ a Non Observant Jew on Shabbos or other Jewish holidays, if the Non Observant Jew volunteers to work on this, since the Non Observant Jew has always worked on Shabbos and Jewish Holidays all his life in other jobs for other non Jewish employers.

2) Can a religious Orthodox Jewish employer refuse to hire or employ a Jew that converted to another religion on Shabbos or any other day, because of the religious Jewish person's beliefs are against someone who left the religion and sees them as an Appostolate?

3)Does a non religious Jewish person have to inform his religious Jewish employer if he is indeed Jewish as well, because he feels that if he does inform the employer, the employer will not allow him to work on Saturday, when the non religious person needs the extra income from Saturday work.

Comment: The last doesn't sound like a question of Jewish law but of secular law.

Comment: closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23519/can-a-jew-own-a-business-that-employs-or-pays-atheist-jews-on-shabbat

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!  In #2, did you mean to include the part about Shabbat?  (I'm not seeing the connection there.)  I assume that in all of these you are asking what *halacha* says on the subject; we can't help you with secular law, first because it's off-topic and second because it varies by jurisdiction.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I believe the OP means "Can a Jew refuse to hire a person to work on Shabbas who is a Jew that converted to another religion?"

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, but that's just a specialization of #1; a Jew who converted to another religion is presumably a non-observant Jew.  (He's still a Jew, after all.)

Comment: These seem like legal questions. CYLA (Consult Your Local Attorney). Also, can you break your questions apart as separate posts?

Comment: Maybe we can transfer to http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The questions can be rephrased to Halachic questions. I suggest OP clarifies before further action.

Comment: I don't understand how #1 can possibly be "No". That'd mean we force people to hire others to work on _Shabas_. Who ever heard of forcing anyone to hire anyone? (Unless a negotiated union contract is in place, but that's another story.)

Comment: I suspect that by "hire," Costa means something like "allow to pick up hours under an existing employment agreement," but we'd need some clarification from Costa to be sure. It's not clear to me whether these are questions about Jewish or secular employment law. If the latter, we'd need to know the jurisdiction in order to answer, but it could still well be on-topic, as it is practical information that directly affects an aspect of religious observance. In any case, I recommend closure until these issues are clarified.

Comment: Closing this as of unclear intent, per most of the comments above. Closure is not forever! Please [edit] the question for clarity, and it can be reopened.

Comment: @MonicaCellio yes, I expect that's what the answer would be but it's still a fine question.

Answer (score 3):

In Mishnah Berurah 243:2 it says that to have a Mumar do work on Shabbos (even if it were permitted to have a non-Jew do the same work) there is Lefnei Iver Lo Sitein Michshol.

Comment: I went to see online what Lefnei Iver Lo Sitein Michsol could mean, and I think I found an explanation.  The religious boss would be 'helping'  my friend commit Torah violations if he allowed him to work.  I understand now why he does not want my friend to work.  Thank You all.